# How to set Windows printer permissions via script

Tags: security, permissions, script, printer

We have new printers coming into our office next month. For them to function properly we need to give the usergroup "Everyone" for the printer on each local machine/computer the permission to "Manage this printer" and "Manage documents."

Any idea on how to achieve this using scripts or some other method so I can remotely push it out to every user?

Our computers are Windows 10 and the printers are not hosted on the server.

```
#Get printer permssions, save to file
(Get-Printer 'ELG-C258' -Full).PermissionSDDL | Out-File 'C:\users\my.username\desktop\testp.txt'
#Load permissions into variable
$perms=Get-Content 'C:\users\ my.username \desktop\test.txt'
#Copy permissions from old printer to new printer
Set-printer 'STR-FRONT' -PermissionSDDL $perms
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yeah sorry, I've tried using some PowerShell commands by loading the printers ACL but PowerShell doesn't recognise the commands Get-PrinterPermission for example... I've managed to however copy printer permissions of one printer to another, but I’m not sure how that’s going to help me. Here is the code I’ve used so far.

Comment: #Get printer permssions, save to file
(Get-Printer 'ELG-C258' -Full).PermissionSDDL | Out-File 'C:\users\my.username\desktop\testp.txt'
#Load permissions into variable 
$perms=Get-Content 'C:\users\ my.username \desktop\test.txt'
#Copy permissions from old printer to new printer
Set-printer 'STR-FRONT' -PermissionSDDL $perms

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the code with proper formatting. It is not readable in a comment.